# What is the difference between "regular" and "reader" macros?

Tags: clojure, macros

I am relatively new to Clojure and can't quite wrap my mind around the difference between *reader macros* and *regular macros*, and why the difference is significant.

In what situations would you use one over the other and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reader macros change the syntax of the language (for example, `@foo` turns into `(deref foo)`) in ways that normal macros can't (a normal macro wouldn't be able to get rid of the parentheses, so you'd have to do something like `(@ foo)`). It's called a *reader* macro, because it's implemented in the `read` pass of the repl (check out the [source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java#L93)).

As a clojure developer, you'll only create *regular* macros, but you'll use plenty of reader macros, without necessarily considering them explicitly.

The full list of reader macros is here: https://clojure.org/reference/reader and includes common things like `@` `'`, and `#{}`.

Clojure (unlike some other lisps) doesn't support user-defined reader macros, but there is some extensibility built into the reader via [tagged literals](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_tagged_literals) (e.g. `#inst` or `#uuid`)

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr***

Macros [normal macros] are expanded during evaluation (E of REPL), tied to symbols, operate on lisp objects, and appear in the first, or "function", part of a form. Clojure, and all lisps, allow defining new macros.

Reader macros run during reading, prior to evaluation, are single characters, operate on a character string, prior to all the lisp objects being emitted from the reader, and are not restricted to being in the first, or "function", part of a form. Clojure, unlike some other lisps, does not allow defining new reader macros, short of editing the Clojure compiler itself.

**more words:**

Normal non-reader macros, or just "macros", operate on lisp objects. Consider:

`(and 1 b :x)`

The [`and`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0-alpha14/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L834) macro will be called with two values, one value is `1` and the other is a list consisting of the symbol `b` (not the value of b) and the keyword `:x`. Everything the `and` macro is dealing with is already a lisp (Clojure) value.

Macro expansion only happens when the macro is at the beginning of a list. `(and 1 2)` expands the `and` macro. `(list and)` returns an error, "Can't take value of a macro"

The reader is reasponsible for turning a character string into In Clojure a reader macro is a single character that changes how the reader, the part responsible for turning a text stream into lisp objects, operates. The dispatch for Clojure's lisp reader is in [LispReader.java](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/LispReader.java#L88). As stated by Alejandro C., Clojure does not support adding reader macros.

Reader macros are one character. (I do not know if that is true for all lisps, but Clojure's current implementation only supports single character reader macros.)

Reader macros can exist at any point in the form. Consider `(conj [] 'a)` if the `'` macro were normal, the tick would need to become a lisp object so the code wold be a list of the symbol `conj`, an empty vector, the symbol `'` and finally the symbol `a`. But now the evaulation rules would require that `'` be evaluated by itself. Instead the reader, upon seeing the `'` wraps the complete s-exp that follows with `quote` so that the value returned to the evaluator is a list of `conj`, an empty vector, and a list of `quote` followed by `a`. Now `quote` is the head of a list and can change the evaluation rules for what it quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Talking shortly, a reader macros is a low-level feature. That's why there are so few of them (just `@`, quiting and a bit more). Having to many reader rules will turn any language into a mess.

A regular macro is a tool that is widely used in Clojure. As a developer, you are welcome to write your own regular macroses but not reader ones if you are not a core Clojure developer.

Your may always use your own tagged literals as a substitution of reader rules, for example `#inst "2017"` will give you a `Date` instance and so forth.